# Future of axis2 for webservices development

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I was just wondering what are peoples opinions on using axis for webservice development?
Is it a viable future proof solution?
I noticed some of the code in their documentation, if you use it, some of the classes are deprecated.

Most of the more useful axis documentation exists on third party sites.

I would be interested in hearing what are peoples opinion on this matter

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason to use Axis I would rather stay with JAX-WS and JAXB. It's included in JDK 6 but could be used with JDK 5 as well. Supported in all modern Java EE containers (Websphere, Weblogic) but could be used in Servlet containers (Tomcat, Jetty) with just few jars from Reference Implementation (Metro). Minimum dependencies and 'just works' for most of the scenarios.